# ¿Cómo imprimir una cadena almacenada en una variable con un for?

Tags: bash, script, shell

Tengo una variable que tiene lo siguiente, quiero aplicarle un for o una funcion que me imprima lo siguiente :

```
#!/bin/bash
VARIABLE=" Hola como estas un gusto saludarte"
```

asi quedaria lo que se imprima

```
        hola
        como 
        estas
        un 
        gusto 
        saludarte
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
#!/bin/bash

VARIABLE=" Hola como estas un gusto saludarte"
IFS=' ' read -ra WORDS <<< "$VARIABLE"
for w in "${WORDS[@]}"; do
    echo "$w"
done
```

Explicación:

- Con `IFS=' '` establecemos el espacio como el separador interno de campos
- y con `read -ra WORDS <<< "$VARIABLE"` leemos y separamos la cadena original en un array que llamaremos `WORDS`
- Por último iteramos por cada palabra del array y la imprimimos por consola

Comment: muchas gracias!!!